# Latex long calculation error: "Missing number, treated as zero"

Tags: errors, calculations

Why do I get the error "Missing number, treated as zero." for case A, while other cases are working? And how to avoid it?

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\newlength\newLen

% Case A (error)
\setlength\newLen{\columnwidth-\tabcolsep-\doublerulesep-\arrayrulewidth}

% Case B (no error)
%\setlength\newLen{\columnwidth-\tabcolsep-\doublerulesep}

% Case C (no error)
%\setlength\newLen{\columnwidth-\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}

% Case D (no error)
%\setlength\newLen{\columnwidth-\doublerulesep-\arrayrulewidth}

% Case E (no error)
%\setlength\newLen{\tabcolsep-\doublerulesep-\arrayrulewidth}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are missing `\usepackage{calc}`.

Comment: Thanks, that is helping. But why are the other cases working?

Comment: they are all in error, you can not by default have expressions in `\setlength`

Comment: actually, there is no error message for cases B to E. See explanation by Phelype Oleinik.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\setlength` is defined as:

```latex
\def\setlength#1#2{#1 #2\relax}
```

so it uses TeX's plain assignment `\register1=\register2`, omitting the optional `=` sign.

Your code then does, after the expansion of `\setlength`:

```latex
\newLen \columnwidth-\tabcolsep-\doublerulesep-\arrayrulewidth
```

which, newlines added for clarity, is the same as:

```latex
\newLen=\columnwidth
-
\tabcolsep=-\doublerulesep
-
\arrayrulewidth=\relax % error
```

and the final `\arrayrulewidth` errors because it's misused there, and if you look at the PDF you'll see two `-` typeset.  The other versions don't actually work: they just don't throw errors, but still typeset spurious `-`.  They don't error because the number of registers is even, so none is misused.

The right way would be to tell TeX that is a dimension expression with `\dimexpr`:

```latex
\setlength\newLen{\dimexpr\columnwidth-\tabcolsep-\doublerulesep-\arrayrulewidth}
```

or `\usepackage{calc}`, as campa said in the comment, which redefines `\setlength` to understand expressions and some other goodies not available with `\dimexpr` only (check out the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/calc.pdf)).

By the way, `expl3`'s equivalent `\dim_set:Nn` already does `\dimexpr` on the argument (though it doesn't add the `calc` syntax):

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\dim_set:Nn \newLen {\columnwidth-\tabcolsep-\doublerulesep-\arrayrulewidth}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: @campa sorry :)

Comment: It happens `:-)`